# google apps script get html table

Tags: html, user-interface, google-apps-script

In my google apps script webapp, I have created a datatable using below

```
var mtdtable = Charts.newDataTable()
```

Then i have created tablechart using the above datatable

```
var mtdchart = Charts.newTableChart().setDataTable(mtdtable)
```

Everything works fine and table in html looks like below. 
[image]

Now what i want to do is to get the data from the above html table in a **ServerHandler**.

Please guide me how could i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you can't get it directly from the chart (the table you create is a chart object).

You can however create a Hidden element (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/hidden) and store your values with the JSON.stringify(value, replacer) function. Then, when you fire the event, you can reference the Hidden element (thru it's id) and recreate the data with JSON.parse(text).

H=I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks Tim for reply. This will partially work because the problem is that user can delete the rows from table using the 'Delete' as shown in image. Due to this the table values that are present in the Hidden element could be different from what was shown in the table in the browser.

Comment: Ok, then you have a show stopper. I would advise to create your own table. I know it's a lot more work, but in my opinion the only way to go forward. This way you could create handlers (on the 'delete' labels) to edit the data in each delete action. It so happens i'm working on a custom 'listview' control library (using all native google UI widgets) I could help you with some samples to get a headstart if your interested in taking that approach.

Comment: when user Deletes a row from webapp the corresponding row is deleted from google spreadsheet. So, what i have done is get the updated data from spreadsheet in ServerHandler. Problem Solved. Great Thanks Tim for your kind suggestions.